# Definition of Torsion Submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, definition

If $R$ is an integral domain one defines an $R$-module $M$ to be torsion-free if the torsion submodule $T(M)=\{x\in M\mid  l_R(x)≠ 0\} $ is zero, where $ l_R(x)$ is the left annihilator of $x$ in $R$. In general, one defines the torsion submodule as $\{x\in M \mid sx=0$ for some non-zero divisor $s\in R\}$ and $M$ is named torsion-free if $T(M)=0$.

What is the problem if we remove the condition " for some non-zero divisor $s\in R$ " ? In fact, what happens if we only define a "subset" of $M$ as $S=\{x\in M\mid  l_R(x)≠ 0\} $?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at $\{x \in R | l_R(x) \neq 0\}$ for $R=\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$? It is equal to the set $\{0,2,3,4\}$, not even an abelian subgroup of the additive group of the ring...

Comment: Furthermore the well known defintion makes sure that $R$ is a torsion-free $R$-module for any $R$. This is definitely desired, since we want free modules to be torsion-free modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In fact, what happens if we only define a "subset" of $M$ as $S=\{x\in M|l_R(x)\neq 0\}$?

You can certainly define this set, and it could be considered a set of "torsion elements" inside $M$, but the set does not have as many nice properties in general. As in the example of $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ given above, $2$ and $3$ are torsion but $3-2=1$ is not, so it is not even a subgroup.

There are, however, other useful ways of defining torsion in rings with zero divisors.

If $R$ is commutative, you can define $m\in M$ to be a torsion element if it is annihilated by a non-zerodivisor of $R$, and the resulting set is a submodule of $M$.

If $M$ is a right $R$ module, and $R$ is any ring, you can also define $m$ to be torsion if its annihilator is an essential right ideal of of $R$. ($m$ is actually said to be "singular," but singularity is just a version of "torsion.") The result is again a submodule of $M$.

Comment: Sorry if this is a little bit off topic, but is there a name for the quotient module $M/T(M)$ or some commonly used notation for it?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I don't know. I'd be tempted to call it the "cotorsion module" but none of the definitions I'm finding for that term look related, so it's probably not the right choice.